# Kibana does not trust Let's Encrypt CA in Kubernetes Helm Setup

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a k8s cluster configured with calico as networking system. I'm running slightly customized versions of helm elastic/elasticsearch and elastic/kibana with security enabled. For security, I use Let's Encrypt certificates.
When starting kibana, the connection to the elasticsearch instance fails with this error

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-06-01T13:09:55+00:00","tags":["debug","elasticsearch","query","data"],"pid":952,"message":"[ConnectionError]: unable to get issuer certificate"}
```

I can resolve this problem, by disabling certificate verification in kibana.
Can anyone see, why its failing?

keystore creation

```
cat cert1.pem > store.pem
cat privkey1.pem >> store.pem
cat chain1.pem >> store.pem
cat fullchain1.pem >> store.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in store.pem -out keystore.pkcs12
```

values_elastic.yaml

```
replicas: 1
minimumMasterNodes: 1

esConfig:
   elasticsearch.yml: |
     xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
     xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
     xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs-gen/keystore.pkcs12
     xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs-gen/keystore.pkcs12
     xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
     xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs-gen/keystore.pkcs12
     xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs-gen/keystore.pkcs12
     xpack.security.enabled: true
extraEnvs:
  - name: ELASTIC_PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: elastic-credentials
        key: password
  - name: ELASTIC_USERNAME
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: elastic-credentials
        key: username
secretMounts:
  - name: elastic-certificates
    secretName: elastic-certificates
    path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs-gen/
protocol: https
service:
  labels: {}
  labelsHeadless: {}
  type: NodePort
  nodePort: 30001
  annotations: {}
  httpPortName: http
  transportPortName: transport
  loadBalancerIP: ""
  loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
  externalTrafficPolicy: ""
clusterHealthCheckParams: "wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=1s"
```

values_kibana.yaml

```
elasticsearchHosts: "redacted its a TLD with appropriate port"

extraEnvs:
  - name: "NODE_OPTIONS"
    value: "--max-old-space-size=1800"
  - name: 'ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME'
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: elastic-credentials
        key: username
  - name: 'ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD'
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: elastic-credentials
        key: password
  - name: 'KIBANA_ENCRYPTION_KEY'
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: kibana
        key: encryptionkey
  - name: 'LOGGING_VERBOSE'
    value: "true"


secretMounts:
  - name: elastic-certificates
    secretName: elastic-certificates
    path: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs-gen/


kibanaConfig:
  kibana.yml: |
    server.ssl:
      enabled: true
      key: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs-gen/privkey1.pem
      certificate: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs-gen/fullchain1.pem
    elasticsearch.ssl:
      certificateAuthorities: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs-gen/fullchain1.pem
      verificationMode: certificate
    xpack.reporting.encryptionKey: ${KIBANA_ENCRYPTION_KEY}
    xpack.security.encryptionKey: ${KIBANA_ENCRYPTION_KEY}
    xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey: ${KIBANA_ENCRYPTION_KEY}

protocol: https

service:
  type: NodePort
  loadBalancerIP: ""
  port: 5601
  nodePort: 30002
  labels: {}
  annotations: {}
    # cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
    # service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
    # service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    # service.beta.kubernetes.io/openstack-internal-load-balancer: "true"
    # service.beta.kubernetes.io/cce-load-balancer-internal-vpc: "true"
  loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
    # 0.0.0.0/0
  httpPortName: HTTP
```

kubectl get pv,pvc,nodes,pods,svc

```
NAME                        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                                 STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/elk-data   30Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    default/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-0                           40m

NAME                                                                STATUS   VOLUME     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-0   Bound    elk-data   30Gi       RWO                           32m

NAME                 STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
node/kubeloadbalan   Ready    control-plane,master   28h   v1.21.1

NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/elasticsearch-master-0              1/1     Running   0          13m
pod/kibana-kibana-7fdbd7c66d-bg5xb      0/1     Running   0          7m1s
pod/nginx-deployment-868c6bb874-tsbg4   1/1     Running   0          40m

NAME                                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                         AGE
service/elasticsearch-master            NodePort    10.97.47.66     <none>        9200:30001/TCP,9300:32185/TCP   13m
service/elasticsearch-master-headless   ClusterIP   None            <none>        9200/TCP,9300/TCP               13m
service/kibana-kibana                   NodePort    10.101.78.90    <none>        5601:30002/TCP                  7m1s
service/kubernetes                      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                         28h
service/nginx-service                   NodePort    10.100.231.27   <none>        80:30000/TCP                    40m
```

From inside the container:

```
kubectl exec pod/kibana-kibana-7fdbd7c66d-bg5xb -it bash

curl -k -u redacted:redacted https://redacted:30001

{
  "name" : "elasticsearch-master-0",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "iXEuqB7iQ9abptIZ_Gp1yg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.13.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "5ca8591c6fcdb1260ce95b08a8e023559635c6f3",
    "build_date" : "2021-05-19T22:22:26.081971330Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.8.2",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}


curl  -u redacted:redacted https://redacted:30001
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

That shows, that even curl cannot verify legitimacy from inside the container. That might indicate that the problem is also located on elasticsearch.
The full Kibana log is a complete mess due to increased verbosity. I can post it on request.

I sank days into that. I'm burnt out and don't know where to continue.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you have provided the CA certificates?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Hi! In values_kibana.yaml, CA should be provided though "certificateAuthorities: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs-gen/fullchain1.pem" doesn't it?
In values_elastic, CA should be provided through the keystore, in which I added fullchain1.pem. Is this wrong?

Comment: There are no CA certificates in fullchain.pem! This is a common misconception. The trusted CA certificates for Internet sites are generally in a bundle included with your operating system. Some containers omit this bundle to save space. We can tell that it is missing because curl did not work. And of course certificateAuthorities: exists to provide a private CA certificate, for networks not meant to be accessible from the Internet.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I see. Indeed I have a ca-bundle.crt and ca-bundle.trust.crt in /etc/ssl/certs, however, what you've written indicates, that the Let's Encrypt CA is missing in that bundle. Is it possible for me to add it via the certificateAuthorities line in values_kibana.yaml? Where do I get the right file? There are quite many CA's on the Let's Encrypt page.

Comment: Well it's very odd for your CA bundle to not have the right CA certificates. They should be there on any currently supported container image. Are you using a very old (years) or unsupported base image? I suppose you can manually find the CA certificate and add it to the bundle, but I don't have the process for that offhand, and it wouldn't solve the underlying problem anyway, just make it a problem for future you.

Comment: The image I'm using is referenced through https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/kibana#requirements which states: "This Helm chart is a lightweight way to configure and run our official Kibana Docker image.". Should function right out of the box and be up to date. Do you think this could be a bug?

Comment: Who knows? Supposedly Kibana's own images are built on centos:7 but who knows if they are up to date.

Comment: By just pulling the kibana image with "sudo docker run -d docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.13.0" and curling from within the container: IT WORKS. 
It should not be a image-related problem.

Comment: Well that's interesting. It suggests that something you have done to customize the image has caused the problem. What that might be isn't really obvious to me though.

Comment: You will not believe it. Adding a wrong CA actually caused the problem. You did help me to solve the problem indirectly. Thank you sir, I wish you the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through discussing the possible root cause of the problem (missing CA) in the comments, I found the solution myself. The issue is caused by adding a wrong CA with

```
elasticsearch.ssl:
  certificateAuthorities: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs-gen/fullchain1.pem
  verificationMode: certificate
```

Deleting those entries resolves the problem.